# how do i pass a hash into input checkbox value in angular 6

Tags: angular, input

this is what i tried ,'i loop through an array of checkboxes, each one looks like this:
item of items:

```
 <input type="checkbox" [value]="{'a': item.title, 'b': item.id}" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">
```

myComponent.ts

```
onCheckChange($event){
    console.warn($event.target.value);
}

//output on console: "[object Object]" .....as a string
```

ideally, i want an array of hash values.How do I send this input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of property binding, you can use interpolation to get the desired result as

```
value="'{a: {{item.title}}, b: {{item.id}}'"
```

Though I still feel that there could be better ways to achieve what you are trying to

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just

```
 <input type="checkbox" (change)="onCheckChange({'a': item.title, 'b': item.id})">
```

Comment: I need the event also to get the checked value(event.target.checked). Of course, I could pass it as another hash item, would also work.

Comment: that can be done too, `(change)="onCheckChange($event, {'a': item.title, 'b': item.id})"`

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the input as 
 JSON.parse($event.target.value); in the on Change function that will give you the proper object that can be used to create array of hash values.

console.warn(JSON.parse($event.target.value); ):

So here you get the proper object and not as string.
If the object values is not printed properly in console you can just use
 JSON.stringify($event.target.value); 
To see the actual value sended in proper string format and not as "[object Object]"